# How do You Install a Private Key on an iPhone Distribution Certificate?

Tags: ios, certificate, xcode8, keychain

When I try to validate my app after archiving, at the end it would say that I need a private key for a certificate.

I am a beginner with swift and I'm trying to complete my first app, and I tried to check out the settings of the certificate, but I couldn't find any way to install the private key for the certain type of certificate.

[image]

I expected to get the private key file, but I didn't.

Thanks,
I_Like_Basketball

Comment: Be patient. You just asked the question 14 minutes ago.

Comment: Have you read this? https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev3a05256b8 Or google searched "how to generate private key for ios certificate"?

Comment: Yes. I already read them.

Comment: Now what should I do?

Comment: Wait until someone answers your question, or try to solve it yourself?

Comment: @James Z I searched all over the web, but I couldn't find any information about it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This may sound silly, but all what I had to do was restart the computer and it worked.